# Spark. How to start making sense of the below execution plan

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand below physical plan.But I have few queries

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(13) Project [brochure_click_uuid#32, brochure_id#88L, page#36L, duration#188L]
+- *(13) BroadcastHashJoin [brochure_click_uuid#32], [brochure_click_uuid#87], Inner, BuildRight
:- *(13) HashAggregate(keys=[brochure_click_uuid#32, page#36L], functions=[sum(duration#142L)])
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(brochure_click_uuid#32, page#36L, 200)
:     +- *(11) HashAggregate(keys=[brochure_click_uuid#32, page#36L], functions=[partial_sum(duration#142L)])
:        +- Union
:           :- *(5) Project [brochure_click_uuid#32, page#36L, CASE WHEN (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW) THEN null ELSE (unix_timestamp(_we0#143, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta)) - unix_timestamp(date_time#48, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta))) END AS duration#142L]
:           :  +- *(5) Filter ((isnotnull(event#34) && NOT (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW)) && isnotnull(CASE WHEN (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW) THEN null ELSE (unix_timestamp(_we0#143, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta)) - unix_timestamp(date_time#48, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta))) END))
:           :     +- Window [lead(date_time#48, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(brochure_click_uuid#32, date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1)) AS _we0#143], [brochure_click_uuid#32], [date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST]
:           :        +- *(4) Sort [brochure_click_uuid#32 ASC NULLS FIRST, date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:           :           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(brochure_click_uuid#32, 200)
:           :              +- Union
:           :                 :- *(1) Project [brochure_click_uuid#32, cast(date_time#33 as timestamp) AS date_time#48, page#36L, event#34]
:           :                 :  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#32)
:           :                 :     +- *(1) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#32,date_time#33,event#34,page#36L] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/e..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,date_time:string,event:string,page:bigint>
:           :                 :- *(2) Project [brochure_click_uuid#6, cast(date_time#7 as timestamp) AS date_time#20, page#10L, event#8]
:           :                 :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#6)
:           :                 :     +- *(2) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#6,date_time#7,event#8,page#10L] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/p..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,date_time:string,event:string,page:bigint>
:           :                 +- *(3) Project [brochure_click_uuid#60, cast(date_time#61 as timestamp) AS date_time#74, page#64L, event#62]
:           :                    +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#60)
:           :                       +- *(3) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#60,date_time#61,event#62,page#64L] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/e..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,date_time:string,event:string,page:bigint>
:           +- *(10) Project [brochure_click_uuid#32, (page#36L + 1) AS page#166L, CASE WHEN (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW) THEN null ELSE (unix_timestamp(_we0#143, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta)) - unix_timestamp(date_time#48, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta))) END AS duration#142L]
:              +- *(10) Filter ((((isnotnull(event#34) && isnotnull(page_view_mode#37)) && NOT (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW)) && (page_view_mode#37 = DOUBLE_PAGE_MODE)) && isnotnull(CASE WHEN (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW) THEN null ELSE (unix_timestamp(_we0#143, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta)) - unix_timestamp(date_time#48, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta))) END))
:                 +- Window [lead(date_time#48, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(brochure_click_uuid#32, date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1)) AS _we0#143], [brochure_click_uuid#32], [date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                    +- *(9) Sort [brochure_click_uuid#32 ASC NULLS FIRST, date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:                       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(brochure_click_uuid#32, 200)
:                          +- Union
:                             :- *(6) Project [brochure_click_uuid#32, cast(date_time#33 as timestamp) AS date_time#48, page#36L, page_view_mode#37, event#34]
:                             :  +- *(6) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#32)
:                             :     +- *(6) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#32,date_time#33,event#34,page#36L,page_view_mode#37] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/e..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,date_time:string,event:string,page:bigint,page_view_mode:string>
:                             :- *(7) Project [brochure_click_uuid#6, cast(date_time#7 as timestamp) AS date_time#20, page#10L, page_view_mode#11, event#8]
:                             :  +- *(7) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#6)
:                             :     +- *(7) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#6,date_time#7,event#8,page#10L,page_view_mode#11] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/p..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,date_time:string,event:string,page:bigint,page_view_mode:string>
:                             +- *(8) Project [brochure_click_uuid#60, cast(date_time#61 as timestamp) AS date_time#74, page#64L, page_view_mode#65, event#62]
:                                +- *(8) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#60)
:                                   +- *(8) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#60,date_time#61,event#62,page#64L,page_view_mode#65] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/e..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,date_time:string,event:string,page:bigint,page_view_mode:string>
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[1, string, true]))
+- *(12) Project [brochure_id#88L, brochure_click_uuid#87]
+- *(12) Filter isnotnull(brochure_click_uuid#87)
+- *(12) FileScan json [brochure_click_uuid#87,brochure_id#88L] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/Interview Preparation/Bonial Interview Related/exercise-S/exercise-S/b..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(brochure_click_uuid)], ReadSchema: struct<brochure_click_uuid:string,brochure_id:bigint>
```

I have the following questions

1. Which is head and which tail i.e Where to start and traverse further.
2. Which is head and which tail i.e Where to start and traverse further
3. what are those numbers at the start of each line eg(13), (11), (5).
4. some lines have +- at start and some have :-. Whats is the difference and when +- get printed and when :- get printed before a line
5. List item
6. whats the meaning of cascading lines eg is as below.

.

```
:        +- Union
:           :- *(5) Project [brochure_click_uuid#32, page#36L, CASE WHEN (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW) THEN null ELSE (unix_timestamp(_we0#143, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta)) - unix_timestamp(date_time#48, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta))) END AS duration#142L]
:           :  +- *(5) Filter ((isnotnull(event#34) && NOT (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW)) && isnotnull(CASE WHEN (event#34 = EXIT_VIEW) THEN null ELSE (unix_timestamp(_we0#143, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta)) - unix_timestamp(date_time#48, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Calcutta))) END))
:           :     +- Window [lead(date_time#48, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(brochure_click_uuid#32, date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1)) AS _we0#143], [brochure_click_uuid#32], [date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST]
:           :        +- *(4) Sort [brochure_click_uuid#32 ASC NULLS FIRST, date_time#48 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:           :           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(brochure_click_uuid#32, 200)
```

7. There are vertical line formed with : connecting two lines.What is the meaning if these lines. How are the two steps connected are related to each other

--- UPDATE AFTER THE ANSWER --

So in the above query plan above or the small ones you mentioned,

1. How to figure out the number of jobs(if possible), job stages and the steps that constitute each job stage.
2. Do a parent and all its children constitute a job stage and if an operator as you mentioned having multiple children on the same level means there are multiple stages to arrive at the parent node.
3. Finally, you mentioned at the start of your answer that there are a lot of file scans, is this happening because the RDD/ Dataframe is recomputed?

Please provide an explanation as detailed as possible. I am a noob  but trying to learn.

Comment: I'd suggest for you to start looking into the Spark SQL - web UI where it shows the plan in a more digestible manner. You can view the plan explanation in the SQL UI as well and that will help you a lot in understanding how are the lines connected together. I'd also suggest to start with simple queries and understand them fully first from the plan perspective and slowly build more and more complicated ones. Also after using the native SQL spark plan visualiser, you will start abandoning the raw text plan more and more.

Comment: provide the code pls

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to answer your questions one by one:

> Which is head and which tail i.e Where to start and traverse further.

The query plan has a structure of a tree, so you should rather ask what is the root and what is the leaf. The leaf nodes are the most nested nodes, in your case it is the `FileScan json` and there are more of them. So you start reading from them and you should get to the root which is on the top of the plan, in your case it is the first `Project` operator.

> What are those numbers at the start of each line eg(13), (11), (5)

It is the `codegenStageId`. During the phase of physical planning Spark generates java code for the operators in the plan. Let me quote directly Spark source code:

> The `codegenStageCounter` generates ID for codegen stages within a query plan.
>     This ID is used to help differentiate between codegen stages. It is included as a part of the explain output for physical plans. 
>     The ID makes it obvious that not all adjacent codegen'd plan operators are of the same codegen stage.

Also the asterisk * means that Spark generated the code.

> some lines have +- at start and some have :-. Whats is the difference and when +- get printed and when :- get printed before a line

Some operators have more children, for example Union, BroadcastHashJoin or SortMergeJoin (and there are other). In that case the children of such operator are displayed in the plan as follows:

```
Union
:- Project ...
:  +- here can be child of project
:
+- Project ...
   +- here can be child of project
```

So this plan means that the two Projects are both children of the Union operator and thus they are on the same level in the tree.

> Whats the meaning of cascading lines

These cascades

```
+- Project
   +- Filter
      +- Window
```

simply mean that this `Filter` is child of `Project` and `Window` is child of Filter and so on. It is a tree and it will stop at leaf node, which has no children. In your plan the leaf is `FileScan json`

> There are vertical line formed with : connecting two lines.What is the meaning if these lines. How are the two steps connected are related to each other

As i explained above the vertical lines formed with : are to connect operators on the same level in the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Does this mean there are totally 13 stages going by the codegen stage number.? Then this also means that 13 times shuffle has happened. Doesn't it?

Comment: @BishamonTen You are welcome. Yes, in your plan there is 13 codegen stages. No, there is not 13 shuffles. Number of shuffles is related to the number of job stages. Job stage is not the same thing as codegen stage.

Comment: So in the above query plan above or the small ones you mentioned, how to figure out the number of job stages and the steps that constitute each job stage. Do a parent and all its children constitute a job stage and if an operator as you mentioned having multiple children on the same level means there are multiple stages to arrive at the parent node. Please provide  explanation as detailed as possible. Finally, you mentioned at the start of you answer that there are lot of file scans, is this happening because the RDD/ Dataframe is recomputed?